# C++ numbers appearing in output stream that have not been input

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, numbers, syntax-error, output

I am getting strange numbers in my output stream that appear in the output's text (in the console). The numbers seem to appear in the same order no matter what numbers I input. They are 0, 80, 0 respectively. Below my code is a sample output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    //write program so that a<=b<c or find a way to sort the program so the numbers are in ascending order

    cout << "This program uses the input of the lengths of 3 sides of a triangle to determine if the triangle is a right triangle." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the length of side 'a'. " << a << "\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the length of side 'b'. " << b << "\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter the length of side 'c'. " << c << "\n";
    cin >> c;
    if ((a * a) + (b * b) == (c * c)) // This means (a^2)+(b^2)=(c^2)
    {
        cout << "This is a right triangle." << "\n";
    }
    else if ((b * b) + (c * c) == (a * a))
    {
        cout << "This is a right triangle." << "\n";
    }
    else if ((a * a) + (c * c) == (b * b))
    {
        cout << "This is a right triangle." << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "This is not a right triangle." << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program uses the input of the lengths of 3 sides of a triangle to determine if the triangle is a right triangle.
Enter the length of side 'a'. 0
2
Enter the length of side 'b'. 80
3
Enter the length of side 'c'. 0
5
This is not a right triangle.

Comment: Okay, I deleted the unnecessary "abc's" in the output but now my console is outputting this: This program uses the input of the lengths of 3 sides of a triangle to determine if the triangle is a right triangle.
Enter the length of side 'a'. 
2
Enter the length of side 'b'. 
Enter the length of side 'b'. 
4
Enter the length of side 'c'. 
Enter the length of side 'c'. 
5
This is not a right triangle.
This is not a right triangle.

Comment: The numbers are the uninitialized values of your variables, which you are outputting with your prompt, that's the ` << a << ` part of each prompt line.  Don't do that.

Comment: No idea why its doing these double sentences

Comment: NEVERMIND IT FIXED ITSELF

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but most of those parentheses in the `if` statements aren’t needed. `if (b*b + c*c == a*a)` does just what you need. `*` binds more tightly than `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
cout << "Enter the length of side 'a'. " << a << "\n";
```

`<< a` instructs the program to print the current value of `a`. At this time `a` has no defined value, but the variable exists, so trying to print it is syntactically correct and compiles. Using this [uninitialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable) `a` results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so anything *could* happen, but what is *most likely* to happen is whatever garbage happened to be in the memory now occupied by `a` gets printed. In your case this turns out to be 0.

The solution for this is don't print out the value of `a`. There doesn't seem to be any need to do it.

```
cout << "Enter the length of side 'a'.\n";
```

Repeat this for sides b and c.

Comment: You should accept this as the correct answer if it solved your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the uninitialized variables `a`, `b`, and `c` before you read them.